# Flowgorithm: how to check if the entered value is integer?

Tags: algorithm, flowchart, flowgorithm

In Flowgorithm, is there a method that allows me to check if the entered number is integer or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question, but the [Flowgorithm help page](http://www.flowgorithm.org/documentation/types.html) says that real numbers (integers) are shown in purple.

Answer (score 0):

If `n == Int(n)` then `n` is an integer number.